# Comparing two sets of pixels to determine whether they belong to the same object

Tags: clustering, classification, image-processing

I have two sets of data, and I want to know if the second set is sufficiently different from the first to be considered different.

More specifically, I have a sample set A from a number of pixels in the vicinity of point X in an image, and another sample B of pixels in the vicinity of point Y in the same image.

I want to know if point X and point Y could be part of the same object in the image (based on color values). For example, if A and B are both mostly blue then the answer is yes, but if A is red and pink and B is blue then the answer is no.

My only idea so far (based on vague memories of a statistics class I took years ago) is to calculate the standard deviation in A and B, and from that calculate a threshold that gives you 95% certainty, and see if they are within a certain distance of each other.  Is this correct?

Otherwise, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: What sort of data you have? It seems like the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) could be appropriate here. It is used to check wether two samples come from the same distribution. It can be easily calculated in R with the command [ks.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html).

Comment: They are pixels from an image.  More specifically, I have a border detection algorithm, but I want to verify borders by checking that pixels on opposite sides of the border are "different".

Comment: I'm used to seeing color defined by values on 3 different variables.  Are you talking about color as something that can be defined by a value on a single variable?

Comment: No, I'm using all 3 RGB values.  So basically, a color is a point in 3D space.

Comment: Well, more accurately, in some parts (e.g. border detection) I'm effectively using one variable: I find the mean, and then use the distance from the mean as a one-dimensional variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare the distributions of the samples. If the border is distinct, using a single hue dimension with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test might suffice. If hue alone does not provide enough separation you'll have to add another dimension. If you want to stick to [chromaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity) (color without the brightness dimension), I would suggest the a* and b* color-opponent dimensions in the [CIELAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB) color model. With two dimensions you can apply [this KS test](http://v-scheiner.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/1166/1/acat2007.pdf). If you want to go whole hog and use all three dimensions, look [here](http://www.subcortex.net/research/code/testing-for-differences-in-multidimensional-distributions).

Comment: Interesting, but I'm curious: why should the algorithm be different when you have more dimensions?  I've just been assuming that a color is a point in 3D space (by RGB), and measure distances accordingly.  Is there an advantage to taking it down to 1 or 2 dimensions?

Comment: When you have a small sample, they will be sparse in high dimensions so obtaining a meaningful, accurate histogram will be more difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emre, I've looked into these, good stuff indeed.